# How to get not-selected dates of a month from bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to get all dates which are not selected from `bootstrap datepicker`

I will select multiple dates as follows

```
using  :multidate: true
```

[image]

now I want to get not selected dates of that month.

**is it possible to get not selected dates of a month ?**

**edit**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $ ("#jdate").datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',  orientation: 'bottom' ,  multidate: true}).datepicker('setDate', new Date());


    });
```

with the above code, I would get selected dates. but I want not selected dates.
please help me out. thank you !.

Comment: Welcome to *StackOverflow*. Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help you more.

Comment: by using datepicker we can select multiple dates , how to get not selected dates of a selected month , what can be example for this ?

Comment: Please note that *SO* is not a code writing site. We help you provided you have tried something on your own. Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: okay sorry @breakpoint . i have given my code please check it.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to do that, but what you can do is, get total days in the month and then find the difference of the days from your selected date value. This will work only if the selected date are in same month.`$('.date').on('changeDate', function(e) {
  var currMonth = new Date(e.date).getMonth() + 1;
  var currYear = new Date(e.date).getFullYear();
  var totalDays = new Date(currYear, currMonth, 0).getDate();
 });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the entire documentation of the *bootstrap datepicker*, there is **no mention** for any such method which will help you achieve what you need.

Hence, as a ***workaround***, this is something that I could come up with (not a fan of this though!) :

```
$('#jdate').datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    onSelect: function () {
        var allDatesHtml = $('.datepicker-days .day');
        var nonSelectedDays = _.compact(_.map(allDatesHtml, function(ele) {
            if (!ele.classList.contains('new') && !ele.classList.contains('old') && !ele.classList.contains('active')) {
                return ele.textContent;
            }
        }));

        console.log(nonSelectedDays);  // gives you all the non selected days of the current month
    }
});
```

> **Please Note :** [compact](https://underscorejs.org/#compact) and [map](https://underscorejs.org/#map) used here are [Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/) functions, which help you ease the code.

Feel free to ask questions/ doubts, if any.

Comment: thank you @breakpoint. is it for the selected month  not selected dates or all dates ?.

Comment: @bharath - this code is for only the current month's non-selected dates. I have updated the answer for more clarification.

Comment: it does not print anything in console

Comment: @bharath please join [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174791/bharath-datepicker-issues) so that we can discuss more there.